# How can I define a Rule for difference between one event and the previous one - Stream mode

Tags: drools

Am trying to detect change in direction of slope
So am trying to calculate dx/dt so need to figure out how to associate event(n) with event(n-1)

Any ideas

Comment: Am going to see if adding a uniqueID to the event Class will allow me to define a rule which fires when event(n) and event(n-1) appear in the working memory

Answer (score 0):

looks like that will work

```
rule "deltas" 
    dialect "mvel"
    salience 1000
    when
        $sQ : MyEvent($id1 : Id) from entry-point MyEventStream
        $sQ2 : MyEvent($id2 : Id, $id1 == $id2 - 1) from entry-point MyEventStream
    then
        System.out.println( "Associated event " + $id1 + " with event " + $id2);
end
```

Comment: This will only work if events have sequential id's and are inserted in that order.